# simple tcp echo program not working when SDL included?

Tags: c++, c, runtime, sdl, winsock

I have this weird problem where whenever I `#include "SDL/SDL.h"`, my windows socket program doesn't execute. It compiles but it doesn't do anything when run. When I remove the `#include "SDL/SDL.h"` header, compile and run, it starts working again??.

I'm trying to make both SDL and my original socket program work but I don't understand whats wrong this.

```
//#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#define MAXLEN 80
using namespace std;

const int winsockVersion = 2;

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) { 

    WSADATA wsadata;
    if ( (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&wsadata)) == 0){
        cout<<"-[ WSAStartup Initialized. ]" << endl;

        char PORT[MAXLEN];
        char SERVER[MAXLEN];
        cout <<"Server: ";
        cin>>SERVER;
        cout <<"Port: ";
        cin>>PORT;

        struct addrinfo hints, *res;
        int sockfd;

        memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

        if (getaddrinfo(SERVER,PORT,&hints,&res) != 0){
            cout<<"-Getaddrinfo unsuccessful." << endl;
        }

        if ( (sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol)) == -1 ){
            cout<<"-Unable to create socket." << endl;
        }

        if ( (connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen)) != -1 ){
            cout<<"-[ Connection Established. ]" << endl;
        }

        cout<<"-[ Client connecting to: ]" << res->ai_addr << endl;

        while(true){
            string text_buff;
            cout<<"Send: ";
            getline(cin,text_buff);
            if( (send(sockfd,text_buff.c_str(),text_buff.length()+1,0)) != -1 ){
                cout<<"-----------------------------------> Data sent!." << endl;
            }

            if ( text_buff == "quit" ){
                break;
            }

        }

    }else{
        cout<<"-WSAStartup Initialization failed." << endl;
        if(WSACleanup()!=0){
            cout<<"-WSACleanup Successful." << endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"-WSACleanup Failed." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compiling with

```
g++ -o draft.exe draft.cpp -I"C:\compilers and libs\Libs\SDL\SDL devep\SDL-1.2.15\include" -L"C:\compilers and libs\Libs\SDL\SDL devep\SDL-1.2.15\lib" -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lws2_32
```

Comment: You have a name clash between your variables and something in SDL maybe? Also, "doesn't do anything" is not enough info. Add trace statements and see what happens. Or run just the preprocessor with gcc -E and look inside the result for something weird.

Comment: Doesn't do anything as in it doesn't continue execution. It idles and doesn't throw any run time error either.

Comment: when I comment out the header, the execution happens and I can connect to my server application by entering the server and port.

Comment: put some printfs at various points to follow program execution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know SDL rewrites the main function with some silly `#define main` trick, it intercepts program main like that.

Therefore, main might not be getting called at all.

If I remember right, your main function (arguments) should be **exactly** `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.