# Program not executed with SDL

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, sdl

I run this program, don't see any output in the console, and it terminates immediatly. What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  //The images

cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    SDL_Surface* hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //Set up screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );

    //Load image
    hello = SDL_LoadBMP( "heldlo.bmp" );

    //Apply image to screen
    SDL_BlitSurface( hello, NULL, screen, NULL );

    //Update Screen
    SDL_Flip( screen );

    //Pause
    SDL_Delay( 20000 );

    //Free the loaded image
    SDL_FreeSurface( hello );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Using minGW, passing libraries:

mingw32
SDLmain
SDL

Signature of main method seems to be correct, it's like here:  [simple tcp echo program not working when SDL included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877885/simple-tcp-echo-program-not-working-when-sdl-included)

Or here, it's stated that the linker subsystem has to be console:
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/376205-defeating-sdl-linker-errors-in-visual-studio-net/

So I tried passing

`-Wl,--subsystem,console -mconsole` both to the compiler and the linker. This builds and starts and is the same as before, no output, no window.

For me it doesn't make sense to pass option console, since, I actually want to see a window, but I'm a complete noob in this, so I have no idea. Just read people saying that SDL requires either program run with console option, OR changing the main method to `WinMain`. But then they also say that this doesn't make sense and SDL is supposed to run with `main`.

I also did a test passing "windows" instead of "console" to the linker, and compiler, also no success (it behaves the same).

I also don't understand why I don't see the output in the console. If I remove all the SDL stuff (specially, the include), it will show the output. Since it also executed very fast, I the main method probably is not being executed at all.

Any help...?

Comment: Do you see the console flash for just a split second?

Comment: No. I tested now putting like 200 outputs and I don't see anything. It says "build finished" and then blank window with "terminated" title. I'm using eclipse btw.

Answer (score 1):

SDL redirects standard output to a file (stdout.txt, IIRC). You should find it in the directory you run your program from.

Check the return value of `SDL_SetVideoMode()`, it has to be non-NULL. A resolution like 640x480 might not be supported by your system.

Comment: There is no text file in my project... only .cpp, .mk, .d, .o and .exe

Comment: Also tried creating the project in the desktop, because of windows 7 right issues, but still not .txt files...

Comment: Ok, I advanced 1 step in the investigation. Trying to run the exe file from the command line shows a windows-error popup "the application could not be started (0xc000007b)". Interesting that eclipse doesn't show anything. I also tried setting up GLUT today and eclipse did exactly the same, nothing. And running the .exe in the console I got a windows popup saying that the glut .dll was missing. I was able to fix GLUT, at least.